# What do you call government inspectors who inspect food establishments?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do you call government inspectors who inspect food establishments (like cafes, food courts etc.) on whether they follow legally mandatory food safety guidelines (it's clean, chefs wear gloves, no insects, etc.)? Each country, I assume, has its own official name for such agencies, but what is the generic term, what do you call those food safety inspectors and these official bodies generally?

Comment: Generic terms are food inspectors, health and safety inspectors, or *name of dept* inspectors, such as *OSHA inspectors*. Those who craft the policies are *regulators*. Of course, another general term used is *busybodies*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A person who does that is called a **health inspector**. It's defined by [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/health-inspector) as 'a public employee who inspects places such as restaurants, shops, factories etc to make sure they are hygienic and do not pose any dangers to health'.